# Facebook remarketing script giving validation error

Tags: javascript, facebook, w3c-validation

I am trying to fix all the validation errors in my site. I have the majority of them however when I add in my Facebook remarketing code

```
 <script>(function() {
   var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
   if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
   }
   _fbq.push(['addPixelId', "1234567890"]);
   })();
   window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
   window._fbq.push(["track", "PixelInitialized", {}]);
   </script>
   <noscript><img height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234567890&amp;ev=NoScript" /></noscript>
```

(sample code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/website-custom-audiences/getting-started)

I get 3 errors, Stray end tag head, Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open and Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

If I take the  tag out I get the rest of the errors from the page but the link above says not to change anything from the code except the pixelId.

I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue and new how to fix it?

Comment: `img` elements are not allowed in `head`, but the `noscript` part puts one there. So you can either ignore that error, or not place that code in the `head` (FB docs say it doesn’t _have to be_ placed there). I would probably leave the script part in head, and put the noscript part inside body (that should not affect its functionality at all.)

Comment: It's validating so that's a plus. Thanks. I'll speak to our analytics guy and see if he notices any affect. Thanks a lot man.